# Unable to connect to dockerised Vue CLI service from host

Tags: docker, vue.js, vuejs2, docker-compose, vue-cli

I have a very basic `Dockerfile` that installs `Vue CLI` and exposes port `8080`:

```
FROM node

RUN yarn global add @vue/cli

EXPOSE 8080
```

I have a `docker-compose.yml` that connects the host port to the exposed one on the container:

```
version: '3'

services:
  vue:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node
    working_dir: '/home/node'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
```

I run up a container with `docker-compose run vue bash` then create a Vue project with `vue create foo`.

Inside the project folder I've added a `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 8080
  }
}
```

When I run the development server with `yarn serve` I see:

```
 App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/

  It seems you are running Vue CLI inside a container.
  Access the dev server via http://localhost:<your container's external mapped port>/
```

While it's showing that it's hosted locally on `localhost` and not `0.0.0.0` this appears to be [a known display bug](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3747).

However, I am unable to reach Vue via `http://localhost:8080` from the host machine.

I've looked at multiple tutorials for setting this up and am unable to work out why I cannot reach the Vue dev server.

Comment: The vue-cli server is for development. Is there a reason you'd prefer to use that over the nginx recommended or something like a express/hapi server?

Comment: I'm trying to use it for local development

Answer (score 2):

I didn't realise that `docker-compose run` doesn't set up the ports defined in the `docker-compose.yml` by default. This can be forced by `docker-compose run --service-ports`.

I've settled on a solution where I've separated running vue cli commands and running the dev server into separate services:

```
version: '3'

services:
  vue-cli:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: auscert/vue:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node
    working_dir: '/home/node/demo'
    command: ['echo', 'Service vue-cli is run only']
  vue:
    image: auscert/vue:latest
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node
    working_dir: '/home/node/demo'
    command: ['yarn', 'serve']
```

This lets me still use `docker-compose run vue-cli` for one-offs and to easily get a shell, while all serving of content is done by a dedicated service. (Adding an `echo` as the `command` for the `vue-cli` service ensures it immediately bails out on a `docker-compose up`.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `docker-compose up` instead of `docker-compose run` which by default doesn't expose the ports (as you've noticed)

> ## What’s the difference between `up`, `run`, and `start`?
>
> Typically, you want docker-compose up. Use up to start or restart all the services defined in a docker-compose.yml. In the default “attached” mode, you see all the logs from all the containers. In “detached” mode (-d), Compose exits after starting the containers, but the containers continue to run in the background.
>
> The docker-compose run command is for running “one-off” or “adhoc” tasks. It requires the service name you want to run and only starts containers for services that the running service depends on. Use run to run tests or perform an administrative task such as removing or adding data to a data volume container. The run command acts like docker run -ti in that it opens an interactive terminal to the container and returns an exit status matching the exit status of the process in the container.
>
> The docker-compose start command is useful only to restart containers that were previously created, but were stopped. It never creates new containers.

src: https://docs.docker.com/compose/faq/

Comment: `run` is absolutely the behaviour I'm after atm

Comment: **fair enough**, I missed it when I was reading the description and I think it may help others that encounter the same issue